# Jq contains query with a variable containing spaces

Tags: json, jq

I've been having an issue with searching a json field that has spaces it in it with a variable containing the search term that also has spaces in it. I've been using the `contains` search but I'm not sure how to make it search the entire phrase.

```
COUNTRY="United States"
CITY='"New York"'

cat testdata | jq --arg COUNTRY "$COUNTRY" --arg CITY "$CITY" -r \
'.wireguard[] | select(.country == $COUNTRY) | select(.city|contains('$CITY'))'
```

When attempting to run the jq command, it has this error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting QQSTRING_TEXT or QQSTRING_INTERP_START or QQSTRING_END (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.wireguard[] | select(.country == $COUNTRY) | select(.city|contains("New                                                                     
jq: 1 compile error
```

It appears that despite the variable containing the qoutes, the space in the variable is stopping the query.

I have also tried `select(.city|contains($CITY))`, but that returns no results (no error).
But, `select(.city|contains("New York"))` query runs perfect fine. Even though the content of the `CITY` variable is `"New York"`.

How do I use a variable with spaces in it with the 'contains' query?

Json I'm testing against:

```
{
  "wireguard": [
    {
      "gateway": "us-ga.wg",
      "country_code": "US",
      "country": "United States",
      "city": "Atlanta, GA",
      "isp": "Datapacket"
    },
    {
      "gateway": "us-ca.wg",
      "country_code": "US",
      "country": "United States",
      "city": "Los Angeles, CA",
      "isp": "Datapacket"
    },
    {
      "gateway": "us-ny.wg",
      "country_code": "US",
      "country": "United States",
      "city": "New York, NY",
      "isp": "M247"
    },
    {
      "gateway": "us-ut.wg",
      "country_code": "US",
      "country": "United States",
      "city": "Salt Lake City, UT",
      "isp": "100TB"
    },
    {
      "gateway": "us-fl.wg",
      "country_code": "US",
      "country": "United States",
      "city": "Miami, FL",
      "isp": "Quadranet"
    },
    {
      "gateway": "us-nj.wg",
      "country_code": "US",
      "country": "United States",
      "city": "New Jersey, NJ",
      "isp": "Quadranet"
    },
    {
      "gateway": "us-nv.wg",
      "country_code": "US",
      "country": "United States",
      "city": "Las Vegas, NV",
      "isp": "M247"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your shell definition of `CITY` means that it's actually got double quotes in the text. That's going to fail to match anything.

Your use of `$CITY` is as a shell variable not a `jq` parameter. Furthermore, because you've come out of quotes where you use it, the shell can parse it - and the JSON gets split at the space between `"New` and `York"`.

Try this instead. I've swapped the case of the shell variables to make it clearer which is a shell variable and which is for `jq`

```
country='United States'
city='New York'

jq --arg COUNTRY "$country" --arg CITY "$city" -r \
'.wireguard[] | select(.country == $COUNTRY) | select(.city|contains($CITY))' testdata
```

Output

```
{
  "gateway": "us-ny.wg",
  "country_code": "US",
  "country": "United States",
  "city": "New York, NY",
  "isp": "M247"
}
```

Comment: Note that `$CITY` may well be a JSON encoded string (on purpose), in which case the user should be using `CITY='"somescity"'` followed by `jq ... --argjson CITY "$CITY" ...`.